# Intellij - Why are Maven and Perforce in Settings and not IDE Settings?

Tags: maven-2, ide, intellij-idea, perforce

I would like to ask why Maven and Perforce settings have to be configured per Project. I understand that the problem is that some projects could be pointing to other source control methods. However as part of my work I routinely recreate projects from scratch and find it a bit annoying that I have to set Maven and Perforce settings for all the projects (again it is the same thing that I do).

Does someone have any interesting shortcuts/workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**File | Other Settings | Template Settings**. Define your settings there and they will be inherited by all the new projects that you create.

Comment: aaha template settings indeed. I happened to search the entire settings section but missed this.